# Magento 2 : How to configure smtp mail functionality for magento 2.2 from localhost ubuntu?

Tags: magento2, email, third-party-module, localhost, smtp

I have installed megaplaza smtp extension for configure mail functionality magento 2.2 but its throwing error during test mail.

I have configured with gmail smtp server.

Can anyone help me regarding this?

Comment: Share your error log here

Comment: undefined getModuleConfig on megaplaza/helper/data.php line 26

Comment: You also need to enable your gmail account for smtp request.

Comment: now i am using magepal and i have configured smtp but i am getting errro Command not implemented i think its error related to ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below url and add this module in your local folder. try to do test connection. the below function is missed. i think it will help you to resolve the issue

https://github.com/mageplaza/module-core/blob/master/Helper/AbstractData.php

```
public function getModuleConfig($field = '', $storeId = null)
{
    $field = ($field !== '') ? '/' . $field : '';
    return $this->getConfigValue(static::CONFIG_MODULE_PATH . $field, $storeId);
}
```

Comment: i have already install core module of mageplaza